# rhel freezing after startup

Tags: rhel, freeze

I installed rhel6 few days ago.it was working fine but today it showed notification that your gnome is missing some configuration.
Now whenever i start pc it freezes at rhel 6.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if there is a software group called Desktop

## yum grouplist | grep -i desktop

Remove that group and then install it again

## yum groupremove Desktop

## yum groupinstall Desktop

Comment: may be i sound stupid but how i can verify if it freezes at startup showing 'red hat enterp. linux 6' only
and sorry for late response.

Comment: i tried rescue installed system.
when i entered 'yum grouplist|grep -i Desktop' 
o/p- bash: yum: command not found.

Comment: Press ESC and see if it shows any message.